# C# Selenium Chrome Driver 103.0.5060.5300 Issue

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Recently started getting an issue with Selenium Chrome Driver. This started happening around the 29th of June. At first it was giving a timeout error and with some changes, began receiving "Chrome not reachable" errors.

I've read a lot of the questions previously posted and tried a bunch of different solutions given. None of those seemed to fix the issue unfortunately.

Normally the "--headless" option is used, but for testing I removed that to watch it go through. The chrome window does appear but it won't navigate to the URL.

The version I'm using is 103.0.5060.5300 on Chrome and the Chrome Driver. Here's the code that's being initiated when it gets called (Note: all the commented out lines have been different solutions I've tried, but this was the original code that has been working until recently).

```
public ChromeHeadless()
        {
            //var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            //service.LogPath = "D:\\chromedriver.log";
            //service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;
            //chromeOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
            //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            //chromeOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            //driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
            //driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
        }
```

The "no-sandbox" or "--no-sandbox" seemed to be a common solutions that didn't have any effect on this issue.

Here is the code that is called when it tries to navigate to the url with the timeouts currently set to 120 but usually 60:

```
private void NavigateToURL(string url)
        {
            if (driver == null) throw new Exception("Please create a new instance, the resources have been disposed.");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, Core.Properties.Settings.Default.SeleniumPageLoadTimeout, 0);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, Core.Properties.Settings.Default.SeleniumAsyncJSTimeout, 0);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You!

EDIT: Error Log Trace:

```
[INFO]: Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}) on port 56389
[INFO]: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[INFO]: [9643e0a93623ae715a18e39a50665f01] COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--headless", "no-sandbox" ]
         },
         "goog:loggingPrefs": {
            "browser": "ALL"
         },
         "pageLoadStrategy": "normal"
      } ]
   }
}
[INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[INFO]: Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may be interpreted incorrectly
[INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-background-networking --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --headless --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-sandbox --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Windows\TEMP\scoped_dir6296_1256668697" data:,
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56392/json/version
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56392/json/version
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56392/json/version
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56392/json/version
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56392/json/version
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:56392/json/version
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
[INFO]: Failed to connect to Chrome. Attempting to kill it.
[INFO]: [9643e0a93623ae715a18e39a50665f01] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR chrome not reachable
[DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

Comment: Does this happen somewhat randomly?  There is a bug in Chrome Dev Tools that would cause this but it goes back to V99 of Chrome.  It has to do with a socks call not returning... but if that were it you'd see it happening in a random fashion.  (Timing issue... you'd usually see a "tab crashed" exception...)  These are timeouts between the driver and the browser so it's nothing you can set except flags that launch the Selenium server.  Try updating the CDP part of Selenium itself.  Latest has CDP 103: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/dotnet/src/webdriver/DevTools

Comment: No, the chrome driver was updated on the 103 release and it worked for a few days. Either later in the day on the 28th or on the 29th it stopped working and hasn't worked since.

Comment: Update the question with the error tracelogs.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium added the chrome driver trace logs.

Comment: The latest Chrome version seems to be **`Version 103.0.5060.66`** but not **103.0.5060.5300** as you mentioned in your question, can you cross check if your browser is updated properly?

Comment: Chrome says it is up to date on version 103.0.5060.114. This is the latest version of Chrome Driver available through NuGet at least outside of 104 Beta.

Comment: I believe those first errors just mean that two drivers or sessions of Chrome are trying to use the same profile directory at the same time.  Check your processes to see if any orphaned drivers are still running.

Comment: I did notice that happening and have tried ending all the chrome driver tasks. Also rebooted the server several times to see if it would help. Neither of these has helped unfortunately.

Comment: Are you setting a specific profile in your ChromeOptions object?

Comment: No, the only thing set previously was "--headless". I've added in the "no-sandbox" to test that solution from other questions.

Comment: You sometimes need the disable gpu flag set when using --headless.  I would begin without any options set to see if one of the options is the culprit.  Also make sure Chrome can be launched manually from the same user that your code is running as.

Comment: Tried the --disable-gpu flag and --disable-software-rasterizer which I found in another question. Neither of those worked. I did try opening chrome with our parameters in a command line and got other errors: DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary. There is 4 that is showing: mf.dll, mfplat.dll, msmpeg2vdec.dll and msvproc.dll. Looking at some other questions/solutions, it may be corrupted or missing files for chrome.

Comment: Does the URL you are navigating to respond with an HTTP redirect? I have had problems with ChromeDriver in the past when a URL responds with a 301 or 302 redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Sorry I haven't looked at this in awhile but we ended up moving the system to a different server and it worked fine. Not sure what the issue actually was.